# React pass state to a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to pass a state to a map function

```
const MenuList = ({login, ìsAuthenticated}) => {
    const [isAuthenticated] = useState(true)
    menuItem.items.push(isAuthenticated)
    console.log(menuItem)
    const navItems = menuItem.items.map((item) => {
        switch (item.type) {
            case 'group':
                return <NavGroup key={item.id} item={item} />;
            case 'authGroup':
                if (ìsAuthenticated){
                    return <NavGroup key={item.id} item={item} />;
                }else{
                    return <div/>;
                }
```

This is my actual code

Comment: Add more code please.

Comment: Are you just trying to display nav items depending on whether or not a user is logged in? there are far easier ways if so?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add more code. Do you want to pass the state as a parameter of the map? or inside the switch command?

Also `isAuthenticated` is a prop on your component and after you create a new const variable with the same name. Why you do this?

Comment: I put a new const to import the  props from redux. My intention is to read the isAuthenticated inside the map function.
I edit the post with more code.